# Current rate of supermassive black hole merges

Tags: black-holes

I think, it is probably not a very common event, and if it happens, it can be maybe one of the ...most interesting events of the Universe.

Considering that the merge of two stellar blackholes were recently enough to excite LIGO from 1.2 billion light years, what would happen if the participant blackholes would be a million times bigger?

What is the currently estimated rate of such events in the observable Universe?

Comment: ["∼2 detections per year by a gravitational wave detector such as eLISA"](http://arxiv.org/abs/1601.06156).